What specs should i look for for a mosfet in this project?
I am a hobbyist and not a native so bear with me. I need a MOSFET that can switch at ~ 100 MHz and withstand up to ~ 40 V and 40 A with a variable duty cycle. If my calculation corrects 1/100 MHz equals 1 Hz per 10 nanoseconds, if the duty cycle is 50%, then 5 ns ON and 5 ns OFF which mean rise and fall time is tight.
So whats specs should i look for? And what are the max values?
Thank you.

A 1.6 kW project of any kind, let alone one with nanosecond speeds, is a lot for a hobbiest to tackle.  At that speed and power level, the gate current alone is going to be several amps.  What are you trying to do?

Have you heard of GaN MOSFETs? You'll need many in parallel to achieve 40 amps.

@AnalogKid making an inverter .

Why 100 MHz and not 100 kHz?

So whats specs should i look for? Didn't you already define your specs in this post? Asking for more specs is unanswerable because it's defined by your needs. Perhaps a better question is asking what you need to consider and providing some details on your intended application and its constraints. Your response, "making an inverter" doesn't provide nearly enough information. I know you mentioned that you're new at this and that's okay. You're learning.

@Colin  "Didn't you already define your specs in this post? " no not exactly for example incase for a 50% duty cycle we said that the ON state is 5 ns but what should be the rise/fall time i dont know is 1 ns 1ns is enought or it has to be in pico range. What else should i also look for.

The frequency you are attempting to run at is unrealistic for an inverter. Describe what you are attempting to do.

@KevinWhite its a Sinusoidal Pulse Width Modulation (SPWM) inverter hope now it is more realistic.

In round numbers, you're talking about a 2 kW FM transmitter.  That's hard.  People are going to keep asking the same question - Why such a high frequency?  Separate from that, there is no such thing as a standard transformer at that frequency and power level.  That kind of transformer design is at least a month of work for an experienced pro.

@AnalogKid we are still talking about mosfetwhat rise/fall time it should have? I have found this one IAUZ18N10S5L420 and still searching. Something is strange about RF mosfet they does not have timing time on their datasheet.

That is because they usually are used in linear amplifiers, not switching circuits.  Why is your frequency so high?

@AnalogKid you didnt answered my question

I did a 200 kHz inverter with GaN transistors.  EMI and common-mode currents were problematic.  I can't imagine switching at 100 MHz, as others pointed out it's not practical for many reasons, and especially so for someone who hasn't spent years in power electronics.

@JohnD my question is about mosfet switching specs not inverters if you can help i will be very thankfull .

OK, sure, look for devices that you can switch in about 1 ns, preferably less, with at least 100 V VDS rating and RDSon and current rating that work thermally and electrically for your 40 A requirement.  Good luck!

@Tintin "you didnt answered my question" - Well you haven't answered ours.  In particular, why you think you need such a high switching frequency.

@marcelm  i was seeking for an answer but all i get is questions  thanks to Jhon D

Please clarify ”equals 1 Hz per 10 nanoseconds”.

@Tintin The questions are to better help you. Your (perceived) requirements are highly unusual and do not match your apparent skill level. By knowing more details, we can better guide you, and perhaps provide alternatives. Rather than arguing with people, you'd do well to actually work with the experts here so you can get closer to a solution to your problem.

To obtain reasonable switching at 100 MHz, you need a transistor that can amplify frequencies at least about 10 times faster. That could be an LDMOS, or a GaN device. The voltage you mention (40V) is no problem, but to find devices for handling 40A of current seems already a bit difficult.
Still you could use what is available, and create a circuit with parallel power stages of course. But that might require complicated power combiners and perhaps a number of expensive power transistors.
So the best advise (as already given in the comments) would be to use a lower frequency.
But for completeness: some of the biggest devices, e.g. like the [BLF188], will handle about 1.5kW in linear amplifier mode, which means that in switching operation it can probably handle more! It consists of two FETs with breakdown voltage specified 135V, which can handle about 40A of current (at the specified 50V supply and with 70% efficiency the supply current clearly must be about 40A and is alternately flowing in each of the devices). Thermal resistance seems low enough (since in your your switching operation the efficiency will be higher than the 70% mentioned), but input C of about 600pF might be difficult to drive! (See [datasheet])
